# Adding a Time frame for Geofencing for monitering time period

Tags: ios, gps, core-location, geofencing

I was experimenting with a geofencing app I have a geofence region for my office and i want to know the percentage of office time i spent there[10 am-6pm].I don't want to monitor past 6pm or before 10 am from MON-FRI.Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: All you can do if you get an exit after 6pm is calculate the time difference between 6pm and "now" and remove that time from your calculations. Similarly if you enter before 10; when you calculate time you need to discount time before 10

Comment: @Paulw11 so it means the monitoring should be enabled all time and just calculate the time spent within the time boundaries.but i don't want to monitor post that time hoping to improve battery usage.

Comment: There isn't really anyway to execute code in the background at specific times.  Geofencing is pretty battery friendly